# Retain Form elements after form submission in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, forms, jsp

I have a form, where for form submission i am using $("#CreateUpdateDetails").submit();  in jquery.

Here on form submission form elements are getting deleted.But i need the form elements to retain as before. How could i do this.Please help me on this.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="ShoppingMetaData" method="POST" name="CreateUpdateDetails" action="CreateUpdateDetails" id="CreateUpdateDetails" 
            onsubmit="return(validate());">
            <div id="updateBatchSelectionError"></div>
            <div class="tool-container">
            <fieldset>
                <ul id="reportSelect">

                    <li>
                        <label for="shopName">  Shop Name :<span class="req">*</span></label>
                        <input name="shopName" id="shopName" type="text" class="required" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="rewardIdCr">Reward :<span class="req">*</span></label>
                        <select name="rewardIdCr" id="rewardIdCr" class="required">
                                <option selected="selected" value="--">Please Select</option>

                        </select>
                    </li>

                    <div class="tool-button-container">
                        <input style="width:70px;display:none;" id="shopUpdate" class="buOrange large" value="Update" onclick="submitUpdateBatch()"/>
                    </div>  

                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        </form:form>


 function submitUpdateBatch(){
    clearError();
    $("#CreateUpdateDetails").submit();
}
```

Comment: do you want to send an ajax request or want to submit the form itself?

Comment: @Krishna Kuntala Can you explain what is submitting form.

Comment: $("#CreateUpdateDetails").submit() this statement is actually submitting the form which passes the control to the server to render the page based on the success or failure. If you want to submit the form and keep the values if there is any error then pass back the object to the view and access the object attribute values inside each form field as "value".

Comment: @Krishna Kuntala But here my problem is onsubmit the form goes off and displays success msg. But i need Form should be there only it has to call the control.Can i do that?

Comment: To do that, you need to submit the form as an ajax request. Normal submission will not work in this scenario.